# Сниффер трафика для веб разработки

Tags: javascript, php

Подскажите хороший софт, которым можно решить задачу. На странице получить ответ от веб сервера. Для того, чтобы протестировать функционал, подменить пакет, который пришел. Скажем, поменять код ответа с 200 на 400.

Видел Fiddler, но он не подходит. Платный для линукса.

Comment: [postman](https://www.postman.com/)

Comment: @InDevX Если я правильно понимаю, то у postman можно создать Mock Server. Но у меня уже есть сервер, который по url:81:/test/example отдает пакет, который мне нужно подменить. Могу ли я сказать mock server, чтобы он "перезаписал существующий?"

Comment: А зачем перезаписывать если можно новый создать?

Comment: devServer.proxy (webpack) + http (node) = возможность переписывать как запросы так и заголовки/данные серверных ответов, затрагивая только development mode (короче, переписывать можно **все**). Это по части метки [javascript]. А насчет похапэ не знаю (курл + строковая замена?).

Comment: @INDevX Скрипты на моем сайте уже отправляют ajax по фиксированному url. Хочу по этому url получить mock данные.

Comment: **ну вот постман и пошлет** эти мок данные

Comment: всегда удивляют эти принцессы. инструмент, которым пользуются миллионы разработчиков, вдруг оказывается совершенно негодным.